# MySQL Unknown column u.id in on clause but column exists

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I've got this tables:

```
users {id = int, name = varchar, pwd = char}
company {id = int, token = char, name = varchar}
user_company {id = int, id_usr = int, id_company = int, name_usr = varchar}
```

I'm trying to get the pwd from users and find out if the user is in the company with the token X from user_company

When I use this query

```
SELECT u.pwd,h.name_usr
FROM users u, company c
    LEFT JOIN users_company h ON c.id = h.id_company AND u.id = h.id_usr
WHERE u.user_name = 'user@domain.com'
    AND c.token = 'f30ea71e7a9d9f0a6710bb46537c0bde'
LIMIT 1;
```

I keep on getting `'Unknown column u.id in on clause'` although u.id exists. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: describe your tables too.

Comment: You are trying to join three tables right  ?

Comment: Do not mix implicit (comma-) join and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, don't use comma-join syntax at all. Also, LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT u.pwd,h.nombre_usr
    FROM company c LEFT JOIN users_company h ON c.id = h.id_company 
    LeFt join users u  on  u.id = h.id_usr
    WHERE u.user_name = 'user@domain.com'
    AND c.token = 'f30ea71e7a9d9f0a6710bb46537c0bde'
    LIMIT 1;
```

The Error was beacause of Join Query . The way it was written is  wrong. We can not apply join two tables with single table at same time.

Comment: I need to join the two tables. I need to know if the user is in the company, but user and companies are not related

Answer (score -1):

sI've got the solution. Thank you all for the help.

```
SELECT u.pwd,h.name_usr
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN company c ON c.token = 'f30ea71e7a9d9f0a6710bb46537c0bde'
    LEFT JOIN users_company h ON c.id = h.id_company AND u.id = h.id_usr
WHERE u.user_name = 'user@domain.com'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This looks like a Thank you comment, thank you comments are discouraged and you additionally added it as an answer which it's not.